# Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIR5kRcn/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: libcrypt.so.1 during running docker-compose

Tags: python, linux, docker, docker-compose, archlinux

I am having this problem running Docker Compose on my machines. I have switched machines and the problem still persists.

Error Message:

```
[40335] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIR5kRcn/libpython3.7m.so.1.0': dlopen: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My OS is fully updated.

I have tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483026/error-loading-python-lib-tmp-meitueauk-libpython3-7m-so-1-0-dlopen-lib-x8), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649177/python3-7-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpython3-7m-so-1-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257338/docker-compose-script-complaining-about-a-python-module-import).

Here is the output of `ldd --version`.

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.35
```

Docker itself is functioning as expected. Docker-compose, however, isn't. Trying to `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose --version` results in the error.

Answer (score 30):

install libxcrypt-compat maybe helps

```
sudo pacman -S libxcrypt-compat
```

https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/libxcrypt-compat

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue in my EC2 instance and I solved it by running this command

```
sudo dnf install libxcrypt-compat
```

This command should be run under root user for it to work.

Answer (score 8):

I fix this issue by created a symbolic link from `libcrypt.so` to `libcrypt.so.1`

Link this: `$ ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypt.so /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1`

Hope it's worked for you

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening and why your solution works? And why this error is occurring even after a clean install? Thank you so much for this answer. It worked.

Comment: It worked for me too, thanks! I was having this problem when trying to execute docker-compose on Arch Linux.

Comment: Hi @Rashiq, it's worked because `docker-compose` required `libcrypt.so.1` as we see in the error message, but when you install `libcrypt` no link `.1` is created, but we have `libcrypt.so`, so you need to created what `docker-compose` want because any way `docker-compose` need `libcrypt.so`. But I not yet know why some lib ask / created some link `.1`, `.2`...  probably for compatibility reason with other system.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution: delete directories ./build and ./dist and run pyinstaller again.

I noticed that if ./build already exists, Pyistaller will reuse the same ./build. Any previous issues in ./build will persist, sometimes with new error messages, because the directory was not recreated. Deleting ./build leads to a new ./build being created next time you run pyinstaller.

This was the original error I was getting.

```
$ ./name_of_executable_created_by_pyinstaller 
[26645] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEITnO6JV/libpython3.7m.so': dlopen: /tmp/_MEITnO6JV/libpython3.7m.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running on manjaro. I had to remove docker-compose, install it back and symlink to it's actual location. I don't know if this works on other distros.

```
sudo rm $(which docker-compose)
```

Now install it back;

```
sudo pacman -S docker-compose
```

Finally create a symlink;

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Confirm it's fine;

```
docker-compose --version
```